# Adding items to a related list in Apex leaves it the same size. Why?

Tags: apex

I'm doing something with some custom objects analogous to this, just because it's structurally very handy to have the parent record and the child record grouped together:

```
Account a = new Account();
Contact c = new Contact();
a.Contacts.add(c);
system.debug(a.Contacts.size());
```

No matter how many contacts I add, the size is always zero and there are never any there. There's no error. Just `a.Contacts` remains empty.

Is this expected?

I know there are a zillion other ways to do this and I've used enough of them that I don't need workarounds, I'm just surprised this doesn't work so I'd like to know if I can make this work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "child relationship" entities on a record (e.g. Account.Contacts) are immutable lists, and can only be populated by a query (or as the result of deserialization from JSON using `JSON.deserialize()`). They are never null, and they actively resist any attempt to change them, such as using `sort()`, `add()`, `addAll()`, `remove()`, and `clear()`. You cannot use any assignment operator, such as `=`, to override the reference that they contain.

### Why?

As for why: They're not intended for general storage of data, but instead meant to be used for enumerating the results of a query. Since this is specialized data, it has special rules. This is outlined in the documentation in the developer's guide. If you need to associate these records together, use a map or a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Not actively enough though. There's no error when adding to the list, it just doesn't add anything. It would be nice to be able to use this as a place for grouping records and it surprised me I couldn't do it. I've been using maps and lists for a long time and only just tried doing it this way. No wonder.

Comment: @Dominic I agree that there *should* be an exception, because other methods, such as `clear()`, do generate exceptions.

Comment: @sfdcfox I just tried calling clear on child entities in a query result and didn't get an exception, and would actually expect none.  Since we know accessing Account.Contacts returns a List albeit a clone, calling any List method should be valid.  It's just pointless without saving a reference to the new List first, as your answer indicates.