# Can I add Parent Record Data to a Trigger.NewMap so that I can use dot notation while looping through the map values?

Tags: apex, map

I have a contact trigger that passes Trigger.NewMap and Trigger.OldMap to an apex method, and then in the apex method, the following debug statement returns null for c.Account.Unit_Type__c:

```
for(Contact c: newMap.values()){
        System.debug('MM ContactTrigger ++++ c.Account.Unit_Type__c = ' + c.Account.Unit_Type__c);
}
```

> **Question:** I know I can do a separate SOQL query using the map as a
>   WHERE condition to get a list of the contacts and the values of the
>   related Account and Account.Field__c's, and then loop through that
>   list instead of the newMap.values(), but is there any way to **ADD**
>   that relationship data to the Trigger.NewMap `<Id,Contact>` map to
>   allow me to traverse the relationships with dot notation while looping
>   through newMap.values like I am trying to do in the code above?

I ask because there is already a lot of code in this class already using the newMap.values() loop but I now want to introduce a new conditional check against related account data. Ideally I'd like to do that without rewriting too much of the class and the easiest way would be if I could just traverse the relationship straight from the map. I am also considering a formula field on Contact but just wanted to check my options first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a trigger context won't include any child or parent relationships. These have to be queried for.  But assuming you have queried the parent Accounts of the Contacts in the trigger and saved the results in a map

```
map<id,Account> aIdToAccountMap;
```

Then, you can modify the sobjects in Trigger.newMap as follows

```
for (Contact c: Trigger.new)
     c.Account = aIdToAccountMap.get(c.AccountId);
```

Note that this technique does not work for child relationships; you could not have a map of ContactIds to a list of Attachments as in:

```
map<ID,Attachment[]> cIdToAttachmentsMap;
```

and do ...

```
for (Contact c: Trigger.new)
   c.Attachments = cIdToAttachments.get(c.Id);
```

Comment: I thought editing child relationships did not work. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/54067/adding-items-to-a-related-list-in-apex-leaves-it-the-same-size-why. Is this now supported?

Comment: @D.S. - I believe I said above that editing in child relationships does _not_ work.  There is a clever (but involved) workaround to this -- see https://andyinthecloud.com/2014/12/03/mocking-soql-sub-select-query-results/

Comment: right you are I totally missed that!

Comment: Thanks for your help! Turns out that in this trigger context I wasn't able to modify trigger.new values because I was already in after update and got the read-only error, but your answer still clarifies the scenario for me. Ultimately since I was after update already, I chose to build my IdToAccountMap and just `.get()` the Unit_Type__c value from the map using c.AccountId as the key. - but I see how I could leverage this in the future in other contexts.

Comment: @MorganMarchese - you could have used `clone()` to get around the Trigger.New issue in after update